# How can I change the background color for the welcome menu

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, page-layout, css

I have changed the color for the upper suite to be blue and the color for the username text to be white.
But I have faced problem , since when the user hover over the username the menu will become white , and the menu text is already white so the menu items will become un-readable, as follow:-

[image]

i tried changing the following CSS:-

```
#welcomeMenuBox {
        background-color:black;}

#zz5_Menu_t{
 background-color:black;    
        }
#zz5_Menu{
 background-color:black;
        }

#zz1_ID_PersonalActionMenu
{
 background-color:black;
        }
```

to make the background color of the menu black, but this will only take effect on the first row for the welcome menu, while the other rows containing (My setting, signout,etc) will stay white.

Any advice of how I can make the background color for the whole menu items black ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if this is what your asking for? if its the menu to the top right that displays the welcome menu that shows your name?

for the background box in f12 developer it shows:

```
ms-SPLink ms-SpLinkButtonInActive ms-welcomeMenu
```

so in css it would be

```
.ms-welcomeMenu
{
   background-color: red;
}
```

for its text

```
.ms-welcomeMenu A:link
{
    color: black;
}
```

when hovering

```
.ms-welcomeMenu A:hover
{
    color: white;
    background-color:black
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the background color for the class ms-core-menu-box?

Comment: changing the back ground color for this class, will take effect on all the drop down menus on the SharePoint site. while i only need to change the background color for the associated menu only (the menu which contains the username).

Comment: in this case, following combination should work
`#welcomeMenuBox .ms-core-menu-box{
background-color:red;
}`